# Default value is getting overwrite by empty value

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this simple insert in to database, but unfortunately default value inside DB which is N/A is getting overwrite by empty value if nothing is inserted in to field. Below is the code for insert, how can I make it to stay N/A?

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO application_forms (application_type) VALUES (%s)", GetSQLValueString($_POST['application_type'], "text"));
```

Comment: to be more specyfic, N/A inside the table is getting overwritten by NULL :( I would like N/A stay

Comment: Did it my self, solution very simple if ($_POST['application_type'] == NULL) {
 
 $_POST['application_type'] = 'N/A';
 } else {
  
  $_POST['application_type'];
  }

Comment: accept my answer as the best one!!! you can not use this site for help, useless site, the best solution is DIY

Comment: If at somepoint you change the Default on the column, to say "Not applicable", you are going to have togo through all your code to find your solution and change each one, doesn't fit my definition of best....

Answer (score 0):

Test for it being empty and if so don't insert.

Comment: as I have got more fields in the form and some of them are mandatory and some of them are not